# How can i copy a Azure vm snapshot to a container in Azure?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have a snapshot of a VM in azure called "testsnapshot" and i have a Storage Account TestStorage with container name Testcontainer. I want to copy this snapshot to the container. I use the following:

```
  az storage blob copy start --account-key <container_key> --account-name <name_of_storage_account>  --destination-blob <name_of_blob_give_any_name> --destination-container <name_of_container>   --source-uri <WHAT IS THIS AND HOW DO I GET IT?>
```

so I do the following:

```
az storage blob copy start --account-key <container_key> --account-name 'TestStorage '  --destination-blob 'Mynewsnapshot' --destination-container 'Testcontainer'   --source-uri <WHAT IS THIS AND HOW DO I GET IT?>
```

I can get the <container_key> no problem , but what is the source-uri  and how do i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i copy a Azure vm snapshot to a container in Azure?

**--source-uri** :  You can use the snapshot export url on **source-uri** section in cmd.

To copy the **Azure snapshot** to a storage container, you can follow the below steps

1. Go to **Azure Portal > Snapshots > select your snapshot > Snapshot export >generate url with time**.

[image]

2. Copy the **generate a secure URL** from portal.

[image]

3. Run the below command to trigger the copy to container.

```
 $sas = "<storage_account-SAS_token" 
 az storage blob copy start --account-name "samplestorage1test" --destination-blob "abcd.vhd" --destination-container "snapshot" --sas-token $sas --source-uri "<snapshot-url"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Here is the cmd to check the status of blob status.

```
az storage blob show --account-name "samplestorage1test" --container-name "snapshot" --name "abcd.vhd" --query "properties.copy"
```

The file has been copied to **Azure storage container**.

[image]

Reference:   [az storage blob copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start)